# inline-block has white space between elements

Tags: css

There is unwanted white space between elements, even when I set `margin: 0`
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WGCyu/418/)

How to remove the white space?

Comment: Do some research before you ask. There is like 100 questions on SO about this. Here, http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/. `font-size: 0;` is the most elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have spaces between your elements.  You have to either remove the spaces or set `font-size: 0` on the container.  If you use `font-size: 0` you'll need to set a font size explicitly on the child elements.

Comment: True enough. Funny this doens't come up more often in practice.